# Property for ComboBox when selectedItem is changed

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I want to do something pretty easy with a ComboBox. I need to call a Command when the selected item is changed. But i can't remember the keyword to use in Xaml.
I would like something like this :

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyVar}" xxx="PersoCommand"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no command for that, just an event, [`SelectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged.aspx). If you want a command to be executed you could for example use `Interactivity` from the Blend SDK, which has `EventTriggers` and `InvokeCommandActions`.